# Trying to output a video using python script

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to run this open source script which renders a scene
https://github.com/leios/simuleios/blob/master/visualization/fourth_dimension/fourth_dimension.py
and then output it to an mp4 file but when I run it I get this error
[image]

Comment: the script is trying to ouput out.mp4 does it have permissions to do so? Have you got a file of that name already.

Comment: I'm not sure about permissions. No, I didn't get any files